# async await with multiple setIntervals

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have two API requests, one that gets called every 5000ms and one that gets called every 30000ms. I want to ensure that each call is completed before issuing a new request to the server. I don't want either of the requests to overlap one another. For example, if func1 API hasn't completed then I don't want to issue func2 API call until that one completes.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
async function vals() {
            try {
                await func1()
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result => display_result(result))
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
                await func2()
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result => display_result(result))
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error: ', error));
            }
            catch(error) {
                return error;
            }
}

vals();
```

Here are func1 and func2.

```
function func1() {
        return setInterval(() => fetch(url, { method: 'GET' }), 5000);
}

function func2() {
        return setInterval(() => fetch(url, { method: 'GET' }), 30000);
}
```

I would expect this to run func1() first, wait for it to resolve, and then run func2(). Instead func1() gets called twice and never gets to func2(). Should the setIntervals be set inside the vals() function instead? Any guidance to make this work would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about using `Promise.all`, it resolves when all of the promises passed as an iterable have resolved.

Comment: If your API can tolerate *infrequent* occurences of both requests happening at the same time, there's a very simple solution for you: Ensure the timeout delays don't have a small common-multiple! `5000ms` and `30000ms` loops will coincide every `30000ms`, but `5000ms` and `29000ms` loops will coincide MUCH less frequently. Better yet, offset the initialization of either loop by `2500ms` - then the loops will never coincide in time.

Comment: I updated my question. I need each API call from either func1 or func2 to run sequentially. Promise.all runs all of the promises in parallel.

Comment: You typically don't use `then` in an *async* function. You should simply await the resulting values and work with them. Furthermore `setInterval` [doesn't return a promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value), so awaiting the result will resolve instantly.

Comment: Have you considered using custom events? The reason to use an event is because of the way they work. If an event handler is being executed at the time another event with the same signature fires, the first event will always execute to completion prior to the next event callback executes. This is a simple way to ensure one task does not start before the first completes (if the tasks, event handlers, are the same).

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is a bit tricky! You have two different intervals spawning tasks (http requests) which take a non-trivial amount of time, and you want to make sure that the tasks don't coincide with each other.

I recommend that instead of immediately activating your requests in the timeout, instead add the requests to a queue of work-to-be-done. That queue will process a number of tasks in serial as quickly as it can.

```js
// In your example your "long-running-tasks" are http requests.
// In this example I'll use a timeout.
let genLongRunningTask1 = async () => {
  console.log('Task 1 start');
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1500));
  console.log('Task 1 end');
};

let genLongRunningTask2 = async () => {
  console.log('Task 2 start');
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1600));
  console.log('Task 2 end');
};

// The tail of the promise-queue. If it resolves we're ready
// to begin a new long-running-task. It's initially resolved.
let queueTail = Promise.resolve();
let queueNewTask = async genLongRunningTask => {
  await queueTail;
  await genLongRunningTask();
};

// Now setup our intervals. We don't directly generate any
// long-running-tasks here - instead we "queue" them, and
// then point the tail of the queue to their completion.
console.log('Starting...');
setInterval(() => {
  queueTail = queueNewTask(genLongRunningTask1);
}, 3000);
setInterval(() => {
  queueTail = queueNewTask(genLongRunningTask2);
}, 6000);
```

In my example the two intervals are at `3000ms` and `6000ms`, so they should run simultaneously every `6000ms` - but you'll see that the queueing logic keeps them nice and separate! You'll never see a new task start before the previous task has ended.

In your case you should only need to edit `genLongRunningTask1` and `genLongRunningTask2` so that they await and process your request. Something like the following:

```js
let genLongRunningTask1 = async () => {
  try {
    // Assuming `func1` returns a "response object":
    let response = await func1();
    
    /*
    Assuming the "response object" has a `json` method,
    and `display_result` is an async method for showing
    the json data.
    NOTE: this use of `await` ensures requests will remain queued
    until the previous request is done processing *and* rendering.
    To begin sending the next request after the previous request
    has returned, but overlapping with the period in which that
    request is still *rendering*, omit `async` here.
    */
    await display_result(response.json());
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  }
};
```

Warning: Be careful that you aren't queuing tasks more quickly than the tasks can complete!

Comment: yikes, you'll get a nasty bug if one of those tasks takes longer than their interval. `queueTail = ...` does not wait for the previous task before that assignment is made.

Comment: You're incorrect, you can try it for yourself - it actually works even if, e.g., `genLongRunningTask1` takes `4000ms` to complete (although the queue will grow infinitely, over time). Re-assigning `queueTail` in this fashion doesn't clobber any tasks already in the queue.

Comment: indeed you're right. it looks like `queueNewTask` awaits `queueTail` before the new assignment to `queueTail = ...`

Comment: @GershomMaes Thanks for your help. Task1 takes about ~2 secs to complete whereas Task2 takes ~7 secs. In this case I still see a new Task2 starting before the last Task1 is complete. Is there anyway to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You may be combining this with your own code incorrectly! See my edit showing an example of how you can go about this with your own code.